# Filenames with spaces breaking for loop, find command

Tags: bash, scripts, find

I have a script which searches all files in multiple subfolders and archives to tar. My script is

```
for FILE in `find . -type f  -name '*.*'`
  do
if [[ ! -f archive.tar ]]; then

  tar -cpf archive.tar $FILE
else 
  tar -upf archive.tar $FILE 
fi
done
```

The find command gives me the following output

```
find . -type f  -iname '*.*'
./F1/F1-2013-03-19 160413.csv
./F1/F1-2013-03-19 164411.csv
./F1-FAILED/F2/F1-2013-03-19 154412.csv
./F1-FAILED/F3/F1-2011-10-02 212910.csv
./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2012-06-30 004408.csv
./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2012-05-08 190408.csv
```

But the **FILE** variable only stores first part of the path **./F1/F1-2013-03-19** and then the next part **160413.csv**.

I tried using `read` with a while loop,

```
while read `find . -type f  -iname '*.*'`;   do ls $REPLY; done
```

but I get the following error

```
bash: read: `./F1/F1-2013-03-19': not a valid identifier
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative way?

**Update**

As suggested in the answers below I updated the scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIR=/usr/local/F1
cd $INPUT_DIR
for FILE in "$(find  . -type f -iname '*.*')"
do
archive=archive.tar

        if [ -f $archive ]; then
        tar uvf $archive "$FILE"
        else
        tar -cvf $archive "$FILE"
        fi
done
```

The output that i get is

```
./test.sh
tar: ./F1/F1-2013-03-19 160413.csv\n./F1/F1-2013-03-19 164411.csv\n./F1/F1-2013-03-19 153413.csv\n./F1/F1-2013-03-19 154412.csv\n./F1/F1-2012-09-10 113409.csv\n./F1/F1-2013-03-19 152411.csv\n./.tar\n./F1-FAILED/F3/F1-2013-03-19 154412.csv\n./F1-FAILED/F3/F1-2013-03-19 170411.csv\n./F1-FAILED/F3/F1-2012-09-10 113409.csv\n./F1-FAILED/F2/F1-2011-10-03 113911.csv\n./F1-FAILED/F2/F1-2011-10-02 165908.csv\n./F1-FAILED/F2/F1-2011-10-02 212910.csv\n./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2012-06-30 004408.csv\n./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2011-08-17 133905.csv\n./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2012-10-21 154410.csv\n./F1-ARCHIVE/F1-2012-05-08 190408.csv: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: It looks you should set `IFS=$'\n'` before the `for loop to make it parse by each line

Comment: Heres some relevant reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs  AND  http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html AND http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Using `for` with `find` is the wrong approach here, see for example [this writeup](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) about the can of worms you are opening.

The recommended approach is to use `find`, `while` and `read` as described [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Below is an example that should work for you:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

This way you delimit the filenames with null (`\0`) characters, this means that variation in space and other special characters will not cause problems.

In order to update an archive with the files that `find` locates, you can pass its output directly to `tar`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -printf '%p\0' | 
tar --null -uf archive.tar -T -
```

Note that you do not have to differentiate between if the archive exists or not, `tar` will handle it sensibly. Also note the use of `-printf` here to avoid including the `./` bit in the archive.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. The only thing is its archiving the `./` as tar. `./.tar
tar: ./archive.tar: file is the archive; not dumped
`

Comment: @Ubuntuser You could add a simple check to see `if [[ "$FILE" == "./" ]]; then` `continue`

Comment: @Ubuntuser: You can avoid the `./` bit with `-printf` see updated answer. However it should not make any difference if it is included or not as it just references the current directory. I also included an alternative `find/tar` combination that you might want to use.

Comment: For those of you wanting to `sort` the results before iterating them you'll need `sort -z` for the null separator.

Comment: There's generally a problem with piping into a loop like this, as _some_ shells consider the right-hand side of the pipe to be a subshell.  So variables you set/change inside the loop / on the RHS don't affect the main script when the loop exits.  Not a problem in this specific case, but still worth bearing in mind. :)  @steeldriver's while loop solution elsewhere on this page avoids that issue.

Answer (score 27):

This works and is simpler:

```
find . -name '<pattern>' | while read LINE; do echo "$LINE" ; done
```

Credit to Rupa (https://github.com/rupa/z) for this answer.

Comment: Simple. Works. Great.

Comment: This is simple and works best for most use cases.

Answer (score 20):

Try quoting the `for` loop like this:

```
for FILE in "`find . -type f  -name '*.*'`"   # note the quotation marks
```

Without quotes, bash doesn't handle spaces and newlines (`\n`) well at all...

Also try setting

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Comment: +1 for $IFS. That descibes the separator character.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I was using `comm` to compare sorted file listings and the filenames had spaces in them, despite quoting variables it wasn't working. Then I saw http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html and the solution of setting $IFS with IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") worked for me.

Comment: Addition of the double quotes, elegant, simple, beautiful - thanks!

Comment: The `for` will loop only once, right? with all the results in the FILE variable...

Answer (score 4):

In addition to proper quoting, you can tell `find` to use a NULL separator, and then read and process the results in a `while` loop

```
while read -rd $'\0' file; do
    something with "$file"
done < <(find  . -type f -name '*.*' -print0)
```

This should handle any filenames that are POSIX-compliant - see `man find`

```
   -print0
          True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline character that  -print  uses).   This  allows  file
          names that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output.  This option corresponds to the
          -0 option of xargs.
```

Comment: this is only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be better off using `find`'s -exec option.

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec tar -cpf archive.tar {} +
```

Find then executes the command using a system call, so that spaces and newlines are preserved (rather a pipe, which would require quoting of special characters).  Note that "tar -c" works whether or not the archive already exists, and that (at least with bash) neither {} nor + need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this to find files that may contain spaces.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for FILE in `/usr/bin/find $DST/shared -name *.nsf | grep -v bookmark.nsf | grep -v names.nsf`; do
    file $FILE | tee -a $LOG
done
```

Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . <find arguments> -print0 | xargs -0 grep <pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

As minerz029 suggested, you need to quote the expansion of the `find` command. You also need to quote all the substitutions of `$FILE` in your loop.

```
for FILE in "$(find . -type f  -name '*.*')"
do
    if [ ! -f archive.tar ]; then
        tar -cpf archive.tar "$FILE"
    else 
        tar -upf archive.tar "$FILE" 
    fi
done
```

Note that the `$()` syntax should be preferred to the use of backticks; see [this U & L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff). I also removed the `[[` keyword and replaced it by the `[` command because it's POSIX.

Comment: About `[[` and `[`, it seems that `[[` is newer and supports more features like globbing and regex matching. `[[` is only in `bash`, though, not `sh`

Comment: @minerz029 Yes. That's what I'm saying. I don't know what you mean by `[[` supports globbing. According to [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), no globbing takes place inside `[[`.

Comment: Try `[ "ab" == a? ] && echo "true"` then `[[ "ab" == a? ]] && echo "true"`

Comment: @minerz029 That's not globbing. These are regular expressions (loosely interpreted). This is not a glob because `a*` means "a followed by any number of characters" rather than "all files whose names start with `a` and have any number of characters afterward". Try `[ ab = a* ] && echo true`  vs. `[[ ab == a* ]] && echo true`.

Comment: Ah well, `[[` still does regular expressions whilst `[` does not. Must have gotten confused

Comment: `./test.sh: line 14: ./F1/F1-2013-03-19: No such file or directory
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive` .. Unfortunately, its not working

Comment: @Ubuntuser Are you sure you have added the quotes correctly? This works well on my system.

Comment: I did. It is not picking up the spaces within the filenames

Comment: @Ubuntuser you should quote every time you use any variable, eg `"$FILE"`

Comment: @Ubuntuser Please update the question with a verbatim copy of how you're running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here break if there is a newline character in the filename. I use the bash more then 15 years, but only interactive.

In Python you can us os.walk(): http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

And the tarfile module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tar-examples

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a script I used to convert audio files.  The file names had spaces, which caused issues for the converted file names.  This solution worked for me on OSX, using zsh:

1. Get all the files using find.  Cut out the slash and dot.  Sort the output.
2. Get the count of all the files.
3. Use the count to loop through the files
4. Use a combination of tail and head to select the files line by line (like a SQL cursor)
5. Handle the file as necessary.

Since I was converting audio, I wanted to use the original filenames (including their spaces) for the new, converted audio files.  The script I used includes FROM and TO parameters for specifying the audio formats.  It also does some additional cutting in the loop to remove the extension.  I was only interested in getting the complete file name, so I found it necessary to remove the extension before converting it using the TO variable.

```
#!/bin/zsh

#  Convert all audio files in directory
#  audioconvert [original] [converted]

export FROM=$1
export TO=$2

export FILES=$(find . -name "*.$FROM" | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort) 
export CNT=$(echo $FILES | wc -l)

while [ $CNT -gt 0 ];do
  export song=$(echo $FILES | tail -n $CNT | head -n 1) 
  export song_title=$(echo $song | cut -d . -f 1) 

  ffmpeg -i $song  $song_title.$TO

  let CNT=$CNT-1
done
```