# How to stock all files with the same suffix into a table?

Tags: command-line, scripts, find, paths

i'm making a little shell script and i want to stock all files with same suffix in a table.

i want something like that :

```
path=/home/user/Documents
suffix="_suffix.txt"
```

and then a function that create a table name files and fill it with file in $path with $suffix suffix.
result :

```
echo files[0]
```

-> /home/user/Documents/project_suffix.txt

```
echo files[1]
```

-> /home/user/Documents/html_suffix.txt

```
echo files[2]
```

-> /home/user/Documents/jokes_suffix.txt.
etc...

I don't want to have in my list other files like "budget.txt"

Thanks for your answers ! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with recent versions of `bash` by using [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) and [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), which is what I assume you mean by tables.

First create some test files:

```
path=/some/where
touch $path/{a,b,c}_suffix.txt
```

Here is an example that puts all files ending in `_suffix.txt` into the `files` array:

```
files=("$path"/*_suffix.txt)
```

To iterate over them you can do something like this:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Or:

```
for i in ${!files[@]}; do
  echo "${files[i]}"
done
```

Note, filenames with spaces and newlines in them will cause problems with this approach. In that case you are better of with a `find`  and `-print0` loop, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343753/70786) for an example and [this write-up](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details.

#### Edit

As noted by *muru*, the whitespace problem may not be as problematic as it used to be, YMMV.

Comment: Instead of `seq ...`, use `${!files[@]}` - that lists out the indexes.

Comment: @muru: I have not seen that one before. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: With proper quoting, spaces and newlines shouldn't be a problem for arrays made from globbing.

Answer (score 2):

What you call a table is usually called an array or a map. In bash, to create such an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays):

```
path="/home/user/Documents"
suffix="_suffix.txt"
files=( "$path"/*"$suffix" )
```

The `*` is a [wildcard](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), which is expanded by the shell to all matching filenames (that have `$path` before it and `$suffix` after). The brackets (`()`) convert the expanded filenames into an array.

Then you can access each element (indexed from 0, instead of 1) using `"${files[0]}"`, `"${files[1]}"`, etc.

For example:

```
$ path=/tmp
$ suffix=_amd64.deb
$ files=( "$path"/*"$suffix" )
$ echo "${files[1]}" "${files[0]}" 
/tmp/vim-athena_7.4.640-1~ppa1~t_amd64.deb /tmp/vim_7.4.640-1~ppa1~t_amd64.deb
```

Comment: why not using `files=( "/home/user/Documents/*_suffix.txt" )` alone?

Comment: @KasiyA Let's say the path and suffix are arguments to the script or something like that. (Also, quote over `*` will prevent globbing.)

Comment: Then in that case `files=( "$1"/*"_$2" )`. The `$1` for path and `$2` for suffix

Comment: @KasiyA `*` outside the quotes!